# trigger with insert inside a select

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to create a trigger in which, only under certain circumstances, an insert is performed on another table. Consider the following code:

```
create table journal (
    pk integer primary key autoincrement,
    dsc varchar(10) not null
);

create table users (
    name varchar(30) primary key not null
);

create trigger users_ai
    after insert on users
begin
    select
        case
            when 1 then
                insert into journal(dsc) values('foo')
        end;
end;
```

I get the following error when I run this code:

```
Error: near line 10: near "insert": syntax error
```

In production, the "1" in the when clause would be replaced by a more complex expression. I've also tried "true" and get the same results. I've also tried surrounding the insert statement in parens and get the same results. Any ideas how to accomplish what I want?

Comment: What is the more complex expression?  Can you include that in your question, or at least include a reasonable proxy for it?

Comment: The complex statement will be a select statement to get a value from a settings table. However, I haven't even written that statement yet. I started by just putting 1 as a first step in development. The current code above is as far as I've gotten.

By way of comparison, if instead of an insert statement I just put a value, like 'foo', then the code works fine.

Comment: Well it would greatly help your question to show us what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. For now, I just want to get the above code working. For now, just assume a true clause. I've reduced the code down to just what produces the error.

Comment: This is the point of my comments; if just a true clause, then just do the insert.  If there be other logic, then do the insert with some extra restrictions.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do an insert with extra restrictions. Let's say the conditional expression is random() > 0. How would you do the insert only if that expression is true?

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured it out. Instead of putting a conditional expression in the block of the trigger, I used a when clause. Here's the code that works:

```
create trigger users_ai
    after insert on users when 1
begin
    insert into journal(dsc) values('foo');
end;
```

If that when expression is changed to something that returns false (say 0) then the insert isn't done. In production, the expression will sometimes return true, sometimes false, which, of course, is the point of this code. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the syntax diagram for "CREATE TRIGGER"](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), you'll see your attempt just doesn't match.  You can, however, simply use the WHEN branch (without needing `FOR EACH ROW`):

```
create trigger users_ai
   after insert on users
   when 1 begin
     insert into journal(dsc) values('foo');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want a `CASE` *statement*, not a `CASE` expression.

```
create trigger users_ai after insert on users
begin
    case
        when ... then insert into journal(dsc) values('foo');
        when ... then ...;
        else ...;
    end case;
end;
```

Note: if your trigger needs access to the data that was just inserted, its definition should the `for each row` option.

Comment: I still get a syntax error: Error: near line 10: near "case": syntax error

Here's the revised trigger that gives that error. I don't think stackoverflow will format it correctly:


    create trigger users_au
        after insert on users
    begin
        case
            when 1 then
                insert into journal(dsc) values('foo');
        end case;
    end;

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an `INSERT ... SELECT` and your expression in the `WHERE` clause.

```
...
INSERT INTO journal
            (dsc)
            SELECT 'foo'
                   WHERE 1 = 1;
...
```

`1 = 1` needs to be replaced by your Boolean expression.